# Get row number of first empty cell in column and store that value in other cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find row number of first empty cell in column and store that row number in Cell Z1.

I tried with Following macro code but it goes into loop forever.
As soon as it tries to set the value in Cell Z1 it again goes into worksheet_change event again and then again in for loop.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In ws.Columns(3).Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then Range("$Z$1").Value = cell.Row: Exit For
      Next cell
End Sub
```

[image]

Please help to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion for readability and per general coding practice I'd avoid the one-liner `If` and use an indented `If/EndIf` block and separate out each action onto a separate line. I don't know if that would be helpful in finding the culprit, but it may. I suspect that the `Exit For` is not executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this code is of any help

```
    Option Explicit

    Function firstEmptyCell(col As Long, Optional ws As Worksheet) As Range

    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    End If

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Cells(1, col)

    If Len(rg.Value) = 0 Then
        Set rg = rg.Offset
    Else
        If Len(rg.Offset(1).Value) = 0 Then
            Set rg = rg.Offset(1)
        Else
            Set rg = rg.End(xlDown)
            Set rg = rg.Offset(1)
        End If
    End If
    Set firstEmptyCell = rg

End Function
```

And the Event code is

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        On Error GoTo EH

        If Target.Column <> 12 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("Z1").Value = firstEmptyCell(12).Row

    EH:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

**Update**: Based on the comments regarding the pitfalls of the change event one could change `firstEmptyCell` slightly and use a UDF only

```
Function firstEmptyCellA(col As Long, Optional ws As Worksheet) As Long

    On Error GoTo EH
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    End If

    Application.Volatile

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Cells(1, col)

    If Len(rg.Value) = 0 Then
        Set rg = rg.Offset
    Else
        If Len(rg.Offset(1).Value) = 0 Then
            Set rg = rg.Offset(1)
        Else
            Set rg = rg.End(xlDown)
            Set rg = rg.Offset(1)
        End If
    End If
    firstEmptyCellA = rg.Row
    Exit Function
EH:
    firstEmptyCellA = 0

End Function
```

Comment: It `may` fail if column full of data (not so important), if range including column `12` and another column is deleted (`Intersect` can fix this) and if rows are hidden (drawback of `End(xlUp)`). Can you imagine a scenario when the sub could fail (seriously)?

Comment: You are right function will not cover a completely filled column L. But it will not fail if you delete a range inlcuding column `12`. Right now I do not see other cases.

Comment: I specified incorrectly: If a range containing its first cell in a column before column `12` and containing at least one cell in column `12` is deleted, it `may` fail. `Target.Column` is the column number of the first (left-most) column (cell) in the range and you're using `If Target.Column <> 12 Then.`, e.g. Fill the range `L1:L3` with values. The result in `Z1` is `4`. Now select e.g. the range `K2:L3` and delete it. `Z1` should contain `2`, but it is still `4`.

Comment: Ah, you are talking about the event which might not work. I was referring to the function `firstEmptyCell`. Yes, true, the event might fail. But the main question of the post was the question _Get row number of first empty cell in column and store that value in other cell_.

Comment: @VBasic2008: Instead of using the `Worksheet_Change` event you could slighlty modify `firstEmptyCell` and use it as an UDF. But that means you would have to make the function _volatile_ which is normally not recommended.

Comment: Nice. Is the line `Set rg = rg.Offset` really necessary or is it there just to increase readability?

Answer (score 1):

### Tricky Enable Events

This is triggered only when a cell in the 12th column (`L`) is changed, otherwise there is no need for it. If you have formulas there, then this will not work and you'll have to use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

**Row of First Empty Cell in Column**

```
Option Explicit

' Row of First Empty Cell in Column
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const TargetCell As String = "Z1"
    Const TargetColumn As Variant = 12   ' (or "L")
    Dim rng As Range

    If Intersect(Columns(TargetColumn), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Set rng = Columns(TargetColumn).Find(What:="", _
          After:=Cells(Rows.Count, TargetColumn), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Range(TargetCell).Value = 0  ' Full column. No empty cells.
        Else
            Range(TargetCell).Value = rng.Row
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

**Row of First Empty Cell After Last Non-Empty Cell in Column**

```
Option Explicit

' Row of First Empty Cell After Last Non-Empty Cell in Column
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const TargetCell As String = "Z1"
    Const TargetColumn As Variant = 12   ' (or "L")
    Dim rng As Range

    If Intersect(Columns(TargetColumn), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Set rng = Columns(TargetColumn).Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If rng Is Nothing Then           ' Empty column. No non-empty cells.
            Range(TargetCell).Value = 1
        Else
            If rng.Row = Rows.Count Then ' Last (bottom-most) cell is not empty.
                Range(TargetCell).Value = 0
            Else
                Range(TargetCell) = rng.Offset(1).Row
            End If
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This is working almost well, one issue, it returns last row number in range.
I want to first empty cell row number. So if L1, L3, L4 is not blank, then it should return 2 (L2), while your code is returning 5 (L5)

Comment: @user1041627: Here you are. The first code should fit your needs. I'm leaving the second code because that's what people often wonder about.

Answer (score 0):

Dont need a loop. Paste this in a module not in a worksheet event unless you want it for every worksheet change.

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.Range("Z1") = ActiveSheet.Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)(1).Row
End Sub
```

if you want it after every change then put it in a worksheet as. This code will not run everytime. It will check if Z1 is empty then enter the valu. Then if Z1 is not empty it will check if the target cell is in column C

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Columns(3)

If IsEmpty(Range("Z1")) Then
    Range("Z1") = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)(1).Row
Else
If Not Intersect(Range("C1:C" & Range("Z1").Value), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Range("Z1") = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)(1).Row
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If your data is huge and you are tracking blank cell on every change then it will take time.. Its not a loop though

Comment: Also, your code is not working. It is not setting any value in Cell Z1.

Comment: Changed the answer